Sourcing a resistor
I'm looking to replace a resistor in a 300w + 300w Mosfet amplifier. It's the one in the photo and while I'm happy removing the old component and soldering in a new one, I'm not sure where to start looking for the replacement part. Any help would be gratefully received. I understand that the coloured stripes denote the ohms, temperature and tolerance, etc., but that's as far as my knowledge goes.


There are two such resistors (one per channel at least). If this one you show us is truly broken (open circuit), you can measure the resistance of the other one, then approximately match the size of a replacement. It will likely have the correct power rating then. You can break the old resistor into two parts to see whether it’s a wirewound type, and if so whether it’s non-inductively wound. The replacement should have the same value (true/false) for both wirewound and non-inductive parameter as the original part. Look up non-inductive winding on google to see how to identify it.

Thanks, yes, the one on the other channel has completely burnt out so this is a photo of the good one. I'll google that now. Now I feel like I'm on the right path - thank you.

The problem with color codes is that you rarely can say one from another. Especially by photo only. If it's yellow-black-black-black-golden then it's 400 Ohm 5% tolerance. Probably, 2 Watts.

These resistors typically do not fail of their own, there is probably another issue. Buy more resistors, because you will need them until the real problem behind that is understood.

Thanks Jens, I did wonder about that. I was hoping it was just a faulty resistor but there's likely more too it I'm sure. I measured 4.8 ohms across the good resistor both ways, I just cant get the colour bands to confirm this. The colours I see are Yellow, Black, Gold, Gold, Black. Although the Gold looks very bronze and definitely metallic so I'm leaning to gold over brown.

The dimensions I took from it this morning were 4.45mm dia on the thinnest part, 14mm length and lead dia of 0.8mm. Closest I can see is 2 watt. So it looks like I'm looking for a 2 watt 4.75 ohm 5% tolerance resistor. If anyone can confirm or reassure, I will break it apart and look at the construction. Thanks

There are many online parts shops. Anywhere from the giants (digikey, mouser, lcsc) to small local shops. Figure out the resistance and power rating, then start searching.
Power rating is directly related to size - bigger size, higher power rating.

After the amp has been off for at least one hour, measure the resistance of the good resistor, then reverse the meter leads and measure it again.  The higher of the two readings is the one closer to the actual value.  Please update your question with the results.
Also, where are you located?

Thanks, I got 4.8 ohms both ways. I've tried to see if I can work out the bands to match up with that as a double check and it doesn't seem quite right. The colours I see are Yellow, Black, Gold, Gold, Black. Although the Gold looks very bronze and definitely metallic. I'm in Cornwall by the way.
